# Render multiple scene on multiple div

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, render

I used `map` function to create multiple scenes. In that `map` function, I created a certain amount of `div` (the amount is according to the scenes). How can I append each scene to each `div`.

When I tried to render, the first model (or all the rest, except the last) display in a blink then disappear, then the last model display. From what I understood is that it has something to do with render function.

But I don't know what to do now. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  let cameraInstance = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
          75,
          window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
          0.1,
          1000
        )
        const rendererInstance = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true })
        rendererInstance.setSize(300, 200)
        const oControl = new OrbitControls(
          cameraInstance,
          rendererInstance.domElement
        )

        const loaderInstance = new THREE.JSONLoader()

        let createSceneInstance = tempInstances.map((tempInstance, i) => {
          let sceneInstance = new THREE.Scene()
          const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x383838)
          sceneInstance.add(ambientLight)

          const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff)
          spotLight.position.set(300, 300, 300)
          spotLight.intensity = 1
          sceneInstance.add(spotLight)

          let newDiv = document.createElement('div')
          newDiv.id = 'instance' + i
          document.getElementById('instances').appendChild(newDiv)

          loaderInstance.load(
            path + tempInstance.json3d,
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            (geo, mat) => {
              let ins1 = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat)
              ins1.scale.set(20, 20, 20)
              sceneInstance.add(ins1)

              cameraInstance.position.set(30, 35, 40)
              cameraInstance.lookAt(sceneInstance.position)

              const render = () => {
                requestAnimationFrame(render)
                oControl.update()
                rendererInstance.render(sceneInstance, cameraInstance)
              }

              render()
            }
          )

          return sceneInstance
        })

        document
          .getElementById('instance0')
          .appendChild(rendererInstance.domElement)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a few minutes to look through the Help Center, specifically [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to include all supporting code and errors with your question. Also, consider creating a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using [snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Also, please take a look at the [three.js examples](https://threejs.org/examples/), filter on "multiple."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give each scene it's own Camera, and OrbitControls ... you can share those between your scenes but then they will all render from the same viewpoint, which I doubt is what you want.

A WebGLRenderer creates it's own canvas element (called domElement), so you will have to append each one to your div like:  div.appendChild(renderer.domElement).

If there are many many divs, it can be very resource intensive to create renderers for each one...

In that case, you can make 1 Renderer for the whole window (that has a window sized div) and control it to only render in the sub-div regions of the window but it requires a more little work:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_elements.html